# shorten long Python indicator

Tags: python, indicator

Here is a code I wrote to help me define a strategy. It works well but I feel the code is too long and I am wondering if there is an efficient way of doing the same with for loops.
The code searches for a set of candlesticks whose bodies are contained within another prior bar. With my clunky method, I could only design is for a minimum of 2 candles and a maximum of seven. Could a for loop be used to fetch as much candles that could fulfill this criteria?
thanks in advance.

```
def eATR(df1,n=14):
    """This calculates the Average True Range of of a dataframe of the open,
    high, low, and close data of an instrument"""

    df = df1[['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close',]]
    # True Range
    df['TR'] = 0
    for i in range(len(df)):
        try:
            df.iloc[i, 4] = max(df.iat[i,1] - df.iat[i,2],
                         abs(df.iat[i,1] - df.iat[i-1,3]),
                         abs(df.iat[i,2] - df.iat[i-1,3]))
        except ValueError:
            pass

    # eATR
    
    df['eATR']= df['TR'].ewm(span=n, adjust=False).mean()
    df.drop(['TR'], axis = 1, inplace=True)     
    return df['eATR']

def contraction(data):
    df = data.copy()

    e_ATR = eATR(df)

    bodyHi = df[['Open', 'Close']].apply(max,axis=1)
    bodyLo = df[['Open', 'Close']].apply(min,axis=1)
    topWick = abs(df['High'] - bodyHi)
    botWick = abs(bodyLo - df['Low'])
    bodyLen = abs(bodyHi - bodyLo)
    canLen = df['High'] - df['Low']

    per = 1.5
    
    contraction = np.where((df['High'].shift(7) >= bodyHi.shift(6))
                          & (df['High'].shift(7) >= bodyHi.shift(5))
                          & (df['High'].shift(7) >= bodyHi.shift(4))
                          & (df['High'].shift(7) >= bodyHi.shift(3))
                          & (df['High'].shift(7) >= bodyHi.shift(2))
                          & (df['High'].shift(7) >= bodyHi.shift(1))
                          & (df['High'].shift(7) >= bodyHi.shift(0))
                          
                          & (df['Low'].shift(7) <= bodyLo.shift(6))
                          & (df['Low'].shift(7) <= bodyLo.shift(5))
                          & (df['Low'].shift(7) <= bodyLo.shift(4))
                          & (df['Low'].shift(7) <= bodyLo.shift(3))
                          & (df['Low'].shift(7) <= bodyLo.shift(2))
                          & (df['Low'].shift(7) <= bodyLo.shift(1))
                          & (df['Low'].shift(7) <= bodyLo.shift(0))
                          & (canLen.shift(0) <= canLen.shift(7) * per)
                          & (canLen.shift(1) <= canLen.shift(7) * per)
                          & (canLen.shift(2) <= canLen.shift(7) * per)
                          & (canLen.shift(3) <= canLen.shift(7) * per)
                          & (canLen.shift(4) <= canLen.shift(7) * per)
                          & (canLen.shift(5) <= canLen.shift(7) * per)
                          & (canLen.shift(6) <= canLen.shift(7) * per)
                          
                          | (df['High'].shift(6) >= bodyHi.shift(5))
                          & (df['High'].shift(6) >= bodyHi.shift(4))
                          & (df['High'].shift(6) >= bodyHi.shift(3))
                          & (df['High'].shift(6) >= bodyHi.shift(2))
                          & (df['High'].shift(6) >= bodyHi.shift(1))                        
                          & (df['High'].shift(6) >= bodyHi.shift(0))
                         
                          & (df['Low'].shift(6) <= bodyLo.shift(5))
                          & (df['Low'].shift(6) <= bodyLo.shift(4))
                          & (df['Low'].shift(6) <= bodyLo.shift(3))
                          & (df['Low'].shift(6) <= bodyLo.shift(2))
                          & (df['Low'].shift(6) <= bodyLo.shift(1))
                          & (df['Low'].shift(6) <= bodyLo.shift(0))
                          & (canLen.shift(0)  <= canLen.shift(6) * per)
                          & (canLen.shift(1)  <= canLen.shift(6) * per)
                          & (canLen.shift(2)  <= canLen.shift(6) * per)
                          & (canLen.shift(3)  <= canLen.shift(6) * per)
                          & (canLen.shift(4)  <= canLen.shift(6) * per)
                          & (canLen.shift(5)  <= canLen.shift(6) * per)
                         
                          | (df['High'].shift(5) >= bodyHi.shift(4))
                          & (df['High'].shift(5) >= bodyHi.shift(3))
                          & (df['High'].shift(5) >= bodyHi.shift(2))
                          & (df['High'].shift(5) >= bodyHi.shift(1))
                          & (df['High'].shift(5) >= bodyHi.shift(0))
                          & (df['Low'].shift(5) <= bodyLo.shift(4))
                          & (df['Low'].shift(5) <= bodyLo.shift(3))
                          & (df['Low'].shift(5) <= bodyLo.shift(2))
                          & (df['Low'].shift(5) <= bodyLo.shift(1))
                          & (df['Low'].shift(5) <= bodyLo.shift(0))                         
                          
                          & (canLen.shift(0) <= canLen.shift(5) * per)
                          & (canLen.shift(1) <= canLen.shift(5) * per)
                          & (canLen.shift(2) <= canLen.shift(5) * per)
                          & (canLen.shift(3) <= canLen.shift(5) * per)
                          & (canLen.shift(4) <= canLen.shift(5) * per)
                         
                          | (df['High'].shift(4) >= bodyHi.shift(3))
                          & (df['High'].shift(4) >= bodyHi.shift(2))
                          & (df['High'].shift(4) >= bodyHi.shift(1))
                          & (df['High'].shift(4)  >= bodyHi.shift(0))
                          & (df['Low'].shift(4) <= bodyLo.shift(3))
                          & (df['Low'].shift(4) <= bodyLo.shift(2))
                          & (df['Low'].shift(4) <= bodyLo.shift(1)) 
                          & (df['Low'].shift(4) <= bodyLo.shift(0))                    
                                                  
                          & (canLen.shift(0) <= canLen.shift(4) * per)
                          & (canLen.shift(1) <= canLen.shift(4) * per)
                          & (canLen.shift(2) <= canLen.shift(4) * per)
                          & (canLen.shift(3) <= canLen.shift(4) * per)
                          
                          | (df['High'].shift(3) >= bodyHi.shift(2))
                          & (df['High'].shift(3) >= bodyHi.shift(1))
                          & (df['High'].shift(3) >= bodyHi.shift(0))
                          & (df['Low'].shift(3) <= bodyLo.shift(2))
                          & (df['Low'].shift(3) <= bodyLo.shift(1)) 
                          & (df['Low'].shift(3) <= bodyLo.shift(0))                    
                                                  
                          & (canLen.shift(0) <= canLen.shift(3) * per)
                          & (canLen.shift(1) <= canLen.shift(3) * per)
                          & (canLen.shift(1) <= canLen.shift(3) * per)
                          
                          | (df['High'].shift(2) >= bodyHi.shift(1))
                          & (df['High'].shift(2) >= bodyHi.shift(0))
                          & (df['Low'].shift(2) <= bodyLo.shift(1)) 
                          & (df['Low'].shift(2) <= bodyLo.shift(0))                    
                                                  
                          & (canLen.shift(0) <= canLen.shift(2) * per)
                          & (canLen.shift(1) <= canLen.shift(2) * per), 1, 0)
    
     

 
    return contraction
```

Here is the output on my chart colored in 'burlywood' when the above criteria is met.

Thanks in anticipation!

[chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Imz2.png)

Comment: Hello! If you're looking for general review and critique of a working piece of code, you should consider posting this to [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: Okay Brian. Thanks for that. I just wanted to shorten my code. The code is doing what I am asking it to anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of the code was to help me identify some candles that met a certain criteria. My implementation was too long and the idea for the implementation didn't look pythonic to me; something more from what i'd do back when I was learning qBasic.
@RufusVS you gave me a hint on how to go about it and this is my final code as opposed to the one I had posted earlier.

```
def contract(data, per = 1.5):
df = data[['open', 'high', 'low', 'close']].copy()

df['bodyHi'] = df[['open', 'close']].apply(max,axis=1)
df['bodyLo'] = df[['open', 'close']].apply(min,axis=1)
df['canLen'] = df['high'] - df['low']
df['eATR'] = eATR(df)
df['contraction'] = 0
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df['canLen'].iloc[i] < (2 * df['eATR'].iloc[i]):
        for j in range(i+1, len(df)):
            if (df['bodyHi'].iloc[j] < df['high'].iloc[i]) and (df['bodyLo'].iloc[j] > df['low'].iloc[i]):
                df['contraction'].iloc[j] = 1
            else:
                break
    
    
    
return df['contraction'].to_frame()
```

[image: inside Body candles]

Thanks once again. it took me a while to get to it but I did eventually. I thought I should let you know.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't exactly understand what you are doing, here's a little pythonic pseudocode of what I think you're trying to do:

```
def fits_in(a,b,per=1.5):
    return (a.hi <= b.hi) and (a.lo >= b.lo) and (a.size * per <= b.size)

def anyfit (candles):
    for i in range(1,len(candle_list)):
        for j in range(i):
            if fits_in(candles[i], candles[j]):
               return True
    return False

candle_list = []   # <- fill this list in from somewhere
 
print(anyfit(candle_list))
```

Comment: This looks like something I should try. I just want to add the candles that meet my criteria into a column of a dataframe so i could use it to display on a graph.

Thanks